# Did the Vuldarian race appear elsewhere in the dcu?

Tags: dc, comics, green-lantern

Did the [Vuldarian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuldarian) race (from [Guy Gardner: Warrior](http://www.comicvine.com/guy-gardner-warrior/49-11894/)) ever appear in other titles in the dcu? Or were they invented in (and limited to) that series?

Not counting [The Way of the Warrior](http://www.comicvine.com/way-of-the-warrior/39-56755/) crossover that ran through Justice League America, Hawkman and Guy Gardner: Warrior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, they did not. The Vuldarians did not make any appearances outside of the Way of the Warrior story arc. Nor have they reappeared in the DCnU. The Vuldarians were already extinct as a species when Guy Gardner was mysteriously found to possess Vuldarian DNA.**

The Vuldarians saga was during a time when the Green Lantern Corps and storylines were in flux. Guy would have an identity crisis and go through several character redesigns including giving him a hand-me down Rocket Red armor, Sinestro's yellow power ring, and finally the Vuldarian morphing powers, before deciding none of these equalled the popularity of the character as a Green Lantern. Gardner has even appeared in the most recent episode of Green Lantern, the Animated Series.

> Guy would join up with Buck Wargo (based on Doc Savage) and his globe-trotting Monster Hunters, which featured obscure Silver Age hero Tiger-Man (Desmond Farr) along with Joey Hong and Rita Muldoon. On an expedition to the Amazon, Gardner found a chalice of the Warrior Water. He drank from it, and this activated alien DNA that was implanted in his bloodline a millennium ago by a space-traveling race called the Vuldarians.
>
> He discovered new, shapeshifting abilities that writer [Beau Smith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beau_Smith) claims was editorially mandated to capitalize on the success of Mighty Morphin Power Rangers, and which would allow him to resume his role as a superhero. When Guy first emerged from having drank the Warrior Water, (in issue 23), his body had assumed the shape of his old exosuit, albeit red instead of gold, and his lost eye had been restored. Guy's body remained that way until the end of the Zero Hour storyline, morphing weapons directly out of his arms as of Zero Hour issue 2.